# Wordpress gives 403 error page on particular string

Tags: wordpress, mod-security

Ok, it's amazing.

I found that if i write, for example, "app/etc/local.xml" within an article, wordpress gives me a 403 error page during save or preview operations.

Now, I tried to decompose the string and i found that the problem is that " /etc/ " piece!! No errors for " etc ", " etc/ ", just for " /etc/ "!

I tried to activate debugging options also but no informations comes back about this error.

I tried to deactivate plugins and so on, but nothing happens!!!

The apache error_log says:

> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match....

It seems that for some kind of string within my posts, mod_security apache's module try to stop an injection.

Comment: Is there any error in web server log file?

Comment: It is on a shared hosting server...i don't think i can access to the webserver log file. Thanks

Comment: Every good hosting solution provide `access_log` and `error_log` files to their clients (if using Apache, for IIS I don't know)

Comment: Ok, found error_log from apache. Post Updated

Comment: @user2270248 - as a general rule, don't truncate error messages that you post to SO... you may cut off a crucial piece of information that others can use to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your hosting service is using [ModSecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity).

My guess is that they have a pattern matching algorithm which sees `etc` in the path of a URL and assumes that it is an attempt to access the `/etc/` part of the filesystem, which they interpret as an injection attack.

Options:

1. Learn how to configure your server to disable this check; this assumes that your hosting provider would permit this
2. Change your app so that it doesn't use `/etc/`

Option 2 seems waaaay simpler.

Comment: Thanks. It's not an app! I'm writing technical articles about Magento with my Wordpress blog, and i use so many paths with etc directory. Moreover, i found that i've the same 403 error  when i try to quote pieces of code with variables or php strings...
I'm ablosutely sure that my provider will not disable this module. I tried to use the htaccess, but without success. Damn, i don't know how to solve this problem!